# how to do codeigniter subquery

Tags: php, codeigniter, subquery

How can I do this kind of process in codeignitor

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $quer1 = "SELECT id FROM table1"; //conside as query examle
    foreach ($quer1 as $value1) {
        ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $value1['id']; ?>

            <ul>
                <?php
                $quer2 = "SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE id = $value1['id']";
                foreach ($quer2 as $value2) {
                    ?>
                <li><?php echo $value2['name']; ?></li>
                  <?php  
                }

                ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php  
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

This method is ok when doing normal php, because we can query and get data from view, but how can I do this controller to view

Comment: And whats your question? Do you need to transform this query into Active Records and if Yes then you can use `JOIN`

Comment: Why you are using framework, if you want to do like this only ?

Comment: yes .. if did this using JOIN how can I view data as List within List as above

Comment: Have a look at [mvc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) first and then [CI model](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/models.html)

Comment: Update your question with table structure

Comment: if you are using mvc pattern... you should look on the ci model... then manipulate it on the controller and pass the result on the view...

Comment: I have a Category table and Subcategory table category has multiple sub categories I need to view category and there subcategories in list view I did JOIN query and get all data to the view but I cant loop the <li> within <ul> <li> as above explained

Comment: You need to prepare the recursive function for that particular

Answer (score 0):

```
   $this->db->select('id');
   $this->db->from('myTable');
   $row = $this->db->get()->row();
   echo $row['id'];
   $this->db->get_where('table2',array('id'=>$row['id']));
```

i hope this will help you to understand how active record works and if you want to do it without active record then use following

```
  $query = "SELECT id from myTable";
   $this->db->query($query);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming:**

```
`table1`

id  |  name
----+-------
1   |  abc
2   |  pqr
3   |  xyz

`table2` (assuming `table_id` is PK and not `id`)

table_id |  id  |  name
---------+------+-------
   1     |   1  | hello1
   2     |   1  | hello1
   3     |   2  | hello2
   4     |   3  | hello3
```

**Model:**

```
public function get_ul_li()
{
    $this->db->select('table1.id, table2.name');
    $this->db->from('table1');
    $this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function xyz()
{
    $ul_li = $this->xyz_model->get_ul_li();
    $arr = array();
    foreach($ul_li as $u)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($u['id'], $arr))
        {
            $arr[$u['id']] = array();
            array_push($u['name'], $arr[$u['id']]);
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($u['name'], $arr[$u['id']]);
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('xyz.php', array('ul_li' => $arr));
}
```

**View:**

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($ul_li as $key => $val) { ?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $key; ?>

        <ul>
             <?php foreach($val as $v) { ?>
             <li> <?php echo $v; ?> </li>
             <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: **Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: controllers/mytest.php

Line Number: 20**    `array_push($u['name'], $arr[$u['id']]);`

Comment: may be this will work.... but I couldn't solved this  **Undefined offset: 1** error... pls help